# How come at a certain joint a truss is a zero force member and at another is isn't?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, free-body-diagram, statics

I have a slight confusion regarding zero force members. I'm analyzing a structure and I started at joint E and found that truss GE has a force of 8.4 [kN]. However, if I analyzed it at joint G, I can see that it is a zero force member.

Now in the official answer to the question, the member is indeed zero force. However, it did raise for me the question of how come at a certain joint it can be analyzed a zero force one and at another it is not? Shouldn't it be zero force in both joints it is connected to - regardless of which one I start analyzing from? How can I avoid this confusion in the first place when analyzing struts?

[image: The structure being analyzed]

Comment: seems to me it is a question of engineering. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-engineering

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the support at G is friction-less, there can be no horizontal force is the segment EG.  I would suggest that you recheck your calculations for point E.  Are these beams allowed to flex at the circled joints?

Comment: The circular joints can be considered as pin joints and indeed, there is no friction at G. I triple checked my calculations and it drives me nuts. If EG is a zero force member, it means that even if I analyze it from joint E I would get that EG is zero? If so, this pretty much solves my question :)